# Keyboard shortcuts require pressing the same physical keys although layout changed

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a laptop with a German QWERTZ-based physical keyboard running Ubuntu 19.10 with Gnome-Shell. When I'm at my desk, I plug in an US-ANSI QWERTY keyboard via USB and switch the input method to "English (international AltGr dead keys)".

When I do it like this, the pysical keys on my US keyboard line up with what I type on my screen, except for key combinations requiring the modifier keys.

For example, zooming in and out in gnome-terminal requires pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>. Doing this on the German laptop keyboard is a totally transparent process. On the US USB keyboard, however, I need to press the keys that are in the same location as on the German keyboard, meaning I'd press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> which is not very intuitive to me.

It's even worse that I need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to undo, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to redo.

This seems only to be a problem on GTK apps. Firefox gets it right and correctly interprets <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> as undo on both pysical keyboards.

I have the feeling that my setup is flawed and that I don't understand the fundamentals of the pysical keys and the sent keycodes and how applications interpret them. Or is this an actual bug?

Comment: Does not seem correct behaviour. Just for debugging purposes, does that persist after you log-out/login or after you reboot (with US keyboard set and attached)?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @vanadium. I can't remember rebooting with the external US keyboard attached before but unfortunately it doesn't change the behavior.